# how to send request after two second in angularjs on keyup event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there any way to send request to server after two `2` second when user stop typing in angularjs .something like **debuncing** .In other word if user type "abc" and  stop wait for two seconds  than hit to server .

currently whenever I type any character it request to server 
here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/npiA2abAo5SEQFMMpKZO?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';


    $scope.keyupevt = function(){
      console.log('xx')
  $http.get("data.json")
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
    });
    }
});
```

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input type="text"  ng-keyup="keyupevt()" />
  </body>
```

Comment: Inputs can be debounced with the `ng-model-options` directive. See [AngularJS ng-model-options Directive API Reference - Triggering and debouncing model updates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#triggering-and-debouncing-model-updates).

Answer (score 1):

Use setTimeout function

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
$scope.name = 'World';


$scope.keyupevt = function(){

  setTimeout(function(){

     $http.get("data.json").then(function(response) 
     {
       console.log(response)
     }
     )}, 2000);//delay parameter of 2 seconds

  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Inputs can be debounced with the `ng-model-options` directive:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <input type="text"
           ng-model="name"
           ng-model-options="{ debounce: 2000 }"    
           ng-change="keyupevt()" />
  </body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-model-options Directive API Reference - Triggering and debouncing model updates](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions#triggering-and-debouncing-model-updates)
- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)